# Nullpointer Exception in YouTube API Auth class - Video Upload using Java

Tags: java, json, authentication, youtube, youtube-api

I want to upload a video on YouTube using Java.
Everything works fine, but at the point where the secrets-JSON for authentication should be read, I get a Nullpointer Exception.

Can please someone help me?

```
Throwable: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:89)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:85)
at Auth.authorize(Auth.java:66)
at Upload.<init>(Upload.java:95)
at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

This is the code:

```
public class Auth {

/**
 * Define a global instance of the HTTP transport.
 */
public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

/**
 * Define a global instance of the JSON factory.
 */
public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

/**
 * This is the directory that will be used under the user's home directory where OAuth tokens will be stored.
 */
private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

/**
 * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
 *
 * @param scopes              list of scopes needed to run youtube upload.
 * @param credentialDatastore name of the credential datastore to cache OAuth tokens
 */
public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

    // Load client secrets.
    Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

    // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential "
                        + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
    FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
    DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();

    // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

    // Authorize.
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
}
}
```

And this is the line where I get the Nullpointer Exeption:

```
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
```

Thanks a lot for your help.
I hope I can fix this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a solution, if you want to use the filepath of the json or the video:

```
//Load client secrets 
URI filePath = new URI (path);      
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream (filePath.toString()));
```

Comment: Why bother putting it into a URI if you're afterwards going to .toString it again anyway? You might as well put the path directly into the parameter of the FileInputStream

Answer (score 0):

For getResourceAsStream documentation:

Returns:A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found

Are you sure that a resource called "/client_secrets.json" exists? Maybe the backslash should not be in the name, if you want to especify a relative path.

Comment: Of course! :D
I also tried to give the direct location of the file, but it doesn't worked as well...

_Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/VideoUpload_YouTube/resources/client_secrets.json"));_

Comment: I tried similar code in an spring mvc application, without backslash, works property for resources placed in my src/main/resources folder (where resources are expected to be). I think you should try without backslash and verify that the resource is in the same path that ClassLoader expects to find it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! You are right. When it's in this directory, it works. Is there no other possibility to send the path of the file?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can not order a full absolute path. As said in documentation: "Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.". So I assume you can oly work with this directory.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help!